# sum asp unbound gridview column

Tags: asp.net

Please I would like to get the sum or total of my total column values in the txtFootTotal text box. I can already multiply quantity and price and the value is shown in the total column so now i need to sum the total values and show the same in the textbox at the footer. Please note that my gridview textboxes are not calling back data from the database as they are unbound.

Here is my gridview

```
      <asp:GridView ID="grvbill" runat="server" 
                ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
                GridLines="None" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="SNo" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="quantity">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="qty" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="unit price">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="price" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="all total">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="total" runat="server" 
                   Height="55px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>

            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFootTotal" runat="server" Width="100px" Wrap="true" style="position:relative; right:500px;"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" 
                        Text="Add New Row" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="" ForeColor="" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: So what have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: I tried a javascript function:                                function update_total() {var grandTotal = 0;
        $("[id*=total]").each(function () {
            grandTotal = grandTotal + parseFloat($(this).html());
        });
        $("[id*=txtFootTotal]").html(grandTotal.toString()); }    Then I tried calling the function using onBlur of the total textbox column. Please I'm open to all possible solutions and I'll confirm which solution worked.